# my data was not deleted from listview after various attempts to clear the listview

Tags: android, listview

I have various fragments but I'm showing the fragments which have bug called ShowItem.java.
I added the data from another fragment and send it to another fragment with the help of setter and getter and add it to the listview which is present on the ShowItem.java fragment. I have a option, when user clicks on the save option then listview whole data is saved into database and clears the database when I came back to the showItem.java fragment then it shows the database and listview data in listview.Here is the code of ShowItem.java

```
public class ShowItem extends Fragment {

// initialization and variable declaration
ArrayList<String> inventoryArray;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
public DBAdapter mDBAdapter;
String date_time = null;
 String invoice_number=null;
String quality=null;
String user;
ListView list_data;
String a,b,c,d;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_item, null, false);
// getting the listview and back button id
list_data = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.idata);
Button button_back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.iback);
mDBAdapter=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
inventoryArray = new ArrayList<>(Inventory.mInventoryModels.size());

// accessing the model and set on the list view
for(UseModel useModel: Home.mInventoryModels){
    user=useModel.getUser();
}
for (InventoryModel model : Inventory.mInventoryModels) {
    date_time = model.getDate();
    invoice_number = model.getInvoice_number();
    quality = model.getQuality();
    inventoryArray.add(0,user+" "+date_time + " " + invoice_number + " " + quality);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inventoryArray);
    list_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

// for showing the data on listview from the database

Cursor cursor=mDBAdapter.selectLogs();

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do{
        a = cursor.getString(1);
        b = cursor.getString(2);
        c = cursor.getString(3);
        d=cursor.getString(4);
        inventoryArray.add(a + " " + b + " " + c+ " "+ d );
    }
while(cursor.moveToNext());
}


button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.defaultFrame, inventory).commit();

    }
});

return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
// TODO Add your menu entries here
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

// menu option
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.send:
        deletingData();

        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        savingData();
        listAdapter.clear();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;

    case R.id.profile:
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.defaultFrame, profile).commit();
        return true;

    default:
        break;
}

return true;
}


// method for saving the data into the database
public void savingData(){

boolean data=mDBAdapter.gettingValues(user,date_time,invoice_number,quality);
if(data){
    try{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

//deleting the data from the database
public void  deletingData(){
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage("Are you sure? This will delete all entries")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mDBAdapter.clearData();
                        listAdapter.clear();
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).show();


}



 }
```

[image]
[image: After saving the data it looks like this]
After adding the data to listview then after saving and clearing the listview it looks like first screenshot but when I came back to showItem.java fragment which have listview then it looks like second screenshot , I think it shows the database and listview value simultaneously.
**Update**

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String database_name="inventoryData";
public static final String table="dataTable";
public static final String id="_id";
public static final String userName="user";
public static final String datetime="date_time";
public static final String invoicenumber="invoice_number";
public static final String i_quality="quality";


public DBAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
// creation of table into a database
 String defaultTable="create table datatable (id integer primary key, user varchar(255), date_time varchar(255), invoice_number varchar(255), quality varchar(255));";
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(defaultTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // if table exists then it will drop the table
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists dataTable");
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}


// saving the data into the table's column
public boolean gettingValues(String user,String date_time,String invoice_number,String quality) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put(userName,user);
    data.put(datetime, date_time);
    data.put(invoicenumber, invoice_number);
    data.put(i_quality, quality);
    // insert values
    long a = database.insert(table, null, data);
    if (a == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

// deleting the data
    public void clearData(){
        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(table,null,null);
}


// selecting the data from the database
public Cursor selectLogs(){
        SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("select * from "+table,null);
        return cursor;
}

}
```

Comment: show your mDatabase adapter

Comment: added the database class

Comment: Your inventoryArray is populated from Inventory.mInventoryModels with a for loop. This is displayed inside ListView. Then you add more items to inventoryArray by cursor. This part will not shown on the ListView as no listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() called afterwards. Therefore what you see in the ListView is not your full inventoryArray and thus have a strange effect. Try move: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inventoryArray); list_data.setAdapter(listAdapter); after you get data from cursor. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inventoryArray); list_data.setAdapter(listAdapter); inside the for loop or somewhere else?

Comment: help please @I_A_Mok

Answer (score 0):

```
yourArray.clear();
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the correct way ; clear arraylist you pass to adapter,then notify adapter that data has chnaged (or cleared).

Comment: thought list_data is your arraylist, thats your listview right,please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try create your adapter after ALL your data is added to list:

```
for (InventoryModel model : Inventory.mInventoryModels) {
    date_time = model.getDate();
    invoice_number = model.getInvoice_number();
    quality = model.getQuality();
    inventoryArray.add(0,user+" "+date_time + " " + invoice_number + " " + quality);
}
// for showing the data on listview from the database
Cursor cursor=mDBAdapter.selectLogs();
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do{
        a = cursor.getString(1);
        b = cursor.getString(2);
        c = cursor.getString(3);
        d=cursor.getString(4);
        inventoryArray.add(a + " " + b + " " + c+ " "+ d + " (DB)");
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, inventoryArray);
list_data.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Same Problem Happening :(, I think I'm gonna fail